# Is there a way to determine what's inhibiting the screensaver?

Tags: linux-mint, screensaver

I have an issue where most often my screensaver will not activate and it's somewhat hard to determine what's preventing it. Is there a way that I can view whatever processes are asking the OS not to display the screensaver?

I'm on Linux Mint 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply went to Screensaver Preferences:

[image]

Made sure that `Activate screensaver when computer is idle` was checked.

Then, I ran `killall gnome-screensaver`, then restarted the screensaver with `gnome-screensaver`. Voila, it worked. How/why, I'm not sure.

As far as having the output shut off, this isn't working yet, but I think it's because I have a weird setup (laptop lid shut, output to two monitors over HDMI and VGA).

Comment: Also: I had to prop open my laptop lid in order to get the monitors to shut off as per the setting in "Power Management."

Answer (score 0):

I guess your mouse is doing tiny movements. It`s been a while, but I experienced this strange behaviour with a mouse that was reacting to sunlight.

So try to remove your mouse...

Comment: Did that, that didn't help.

Comment: I am out of ideas here. I once tried to research some things about DPMS and did not come up with much information.